# C# 「現在のコンテキストに存在しません。」

Tags: c#

```
public enum enumMessageType
{
    mtA, mtB, mtC, mtD
}
public class Controller
{
    private device devices[];
    public device getDeviceFromEnum(enumMessageType mt)
    {
        switch (mt)
        {
            case mtA: <-ここ
                return devices[0];
        (後略)
```

「ここ」で「名前 'mtA' は現在のコンテキスト内に存在しません。」とエラーがでます。
ぐぐってみたのですが、似たようなものはありませんでした。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: "case enumMessageType.mtA:" とする必要があるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: できました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C言語等と異なり、C# の列挙型は型名を付ける必要があります。
<sub>(C++11 には enum class がありますが)</sub>

```
public enum MessageType
{
    A, B, C, D
}

public class Controller
{
    private device devices[];
    public device GetDeviceFromEnum(MessageType mt)
    {
        switch (mt)
        {
            case MessageType.A:
                return devices[0];
        (後略)
```

[列挙型 - C# によるプログラミング入門 | ++C++; // 未確認飛行 C](http://ufcpp.net/study/csharp/st_enum.html)

Comment: できました。ありがとうございます。